# conditional column splitting in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdZHW.png)

the column has both data like "a" and data like "8a"

a

a

a

a

8a

8a

8a

I have been trying to split a column which has values as either "a" or "8a" into two columns in order to have a column with the value "a" and a column with the "8" when 8 is present. I have tried to separate by position but it doesn't work as the position of "a" varies if the "8" is present or not and I am not sure what to do. I would be grateful for any help,

Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

We could use `separate`.  Specify regex lookaround to split at the junction between a number and the letter a

```
library(tidyverse)
dat %>% 
   separate(initiativen, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep= "(?<=8)(?=a)")
```

More general cases would be to split between any number and any letter

```
dat %>% 
   separate(initiativen, into = c('col1', 'col2'), sep= "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])")
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(initiativen = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '8a'), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R you could do

```
dat <- data.frame(questionn = rep("008", 7),
                  initiativen = c(rep("a", 4), rep("8a", 3)),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)                      


eight <- grepl("^8", dat$initiativen)
split(dat, eight)
#$`FALSE`
#  questionn initiativen
#1       008           a
#2       008           a
#3       008           a
#4       008           a
#
#$`TRUE`
#  questionn initiativen
#5       008          8a
#6       008          8a
#7       008          8a
```

If you want to split just the column, pass that column to `split` as the first argument.

```
split(dat$initiativen, eight)
#$`FALSE`
#[1] "a" "a" "a" "a"
#
#$`TRUE`
#[1] "8a" "8a" "8a"
```